# Сделать так, чтобы QTextEdit не реагировал на события мыши

Tags: qt

У меня есть MainWindow, кастомный GraphicsView и есть QGraphicsScene. Я добавляю в QGraphicsScene QGraphicsRectItem , в который добавляю QTextEdit (Делаю все это, чтобы была возможность поворачивать QTextEdit). Хочу отключить setMouseTracking у QTextEdit(чтобы он не реагировал на события мыши). поставил setMouseTracking(false) в MainWindow , GraphicsView, QTextEdit,  но не работает. Мне просто нужно, чтобы не менялся CursorShape, когда курсор внутри QTextEdit при определенных условиях, но и иногда надо,чтобы реагировал.

Comment: а если сделать `textEdit->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor)`?

Comment: Ну работает textEdit->viewport()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor). Если без viewport-a , то не меняет. Но я хочу чтобы он вообще не реагировал. Если через фильтр, то не знаю, просто не будет ли это затратно. Например иногда надо, чтобы был Qt::ArrowCursor , а иногда (допустим) Qt::BusyCursor, не будет ли затратным, если я фильтр переопределю?

Comment: не будет, делай фильтр и не парься